# Codeigniter - how to integrate third-party library installed via composer

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try integrate external php inpost library:
https://github.com/imper86/php-inpost-api

I run composer install:

```
 - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.27.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/options-resolver (v5.4.11): Extracting archive
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing php-http/client-common (2.6.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing imper86/php-http-cache-plugin (2.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing imper86/http-client-builder (v2.0.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing imper86/php-inpost-api (v1.1.9): Extracting archive
```

Now all this files I have in public_html/vendor folder.

[structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxxN7.png)

I fallow to this example guide:

```
https://www.wdb24.com/how-to-integrate-faker-as-a-third-party-into-codeigniter/
```

But for me looks like I have dirrfrent this files structure. Example when I rename folder src and call:

```
include APPPATH.'/third_party/imper86/autoload.php';
```

but in imper86 I have 3 extra folders with containst src folder like `http-client-builder php-http-cache-plugin and php-inpost-api`

Also as is shown in log from composer installation, this library require also `symfony psr and php-http`

and now im not sure how to now copy this folders to correct structure to working together everything.